# python dataframe get specific word

Tags: python, apply

the dataframe like this:

```
stop_wd=['the','a']
df2=pandas.DataFrame({'col1':[1,3,4],
                      'col2':['the future','a dog','data frame']})
```

the `df2`

```
    col1    col2
0   1   the future
1   3   a dog
2   4   data frame
```

the result I wanted to get:

```
   col1 col2
0   1   future
1   3   dog
2   4   data frame
```

the `stop_wd=['the','a']` so the `the future` should remove the `the`. the `a dog` should remove the `a`. the `data frame` remove nothing.

I try to use `apply`:

```
def word(x,stop_wd=stop_wd):
    for r in stop_wd:
        if r in x.split():
            x=x.split(' ').remove(r)
            return x
        else:
            return x
df2.col2=df2.col2.apply(word)
```

but this doesn't work. I only get this result:

```
    col1    col2
  0 1   None
  1 3   a dog
  2 4   data frame
```

Comment: Thanks for this question. It actually helped me learn how to deal with similar situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is almost there - your `word` function is just slightly wrong.

I would use a list comprehension, which is very easy to read and has the advantage of only splitting the text once (in your solution, you call `.split()` for every word in the `stop_wd` list).

```
def word(text, stop_wd=stop_wd):
    return ' '.join([word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stop_wd])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your look terminates before all the possibilities are tried

```
import pandas 
stop_wd=['the','a']
df2=pandas.DataFrame({'col1':[1,3,4],
                      'col2':['the future','a dog','data frame']})

def word(x,stop_wd=stop_wd):
    for r in stop_wd:
        if r in x.split():
            x=x.replace(r,'')
    return x

df2.col2=df2.col2.apply(word)
```

Yields output of

```
 future
 dog
 data frame
```

Which is what I think you are looking for